# PHP Contact form sending no content in emails

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I need help, i'm trying to set up a contact form, I have the code and think I have it set up correctly with HTML and PHP. When I submit to test it on my testsite it send an email through but the email is blank.

Thanks in advance if you can help me please.

[image: Screen shot of blank content being sent to email]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-right">

                    <form name="contactform" action="mailer.php" method="post" role="form" enctype="text/plain">
                        <div class="styled-input agile-styled-input-top">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="styled-input">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"> 
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <span></span>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="styled-input">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="styled-input">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>   
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                    </form>
        </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "laura@ironcladdesign.co.uk";
$subject = "Enquiry from CK9C Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You! We will be in touch very soon";
?>
```

Comment: Can you confirm message is not blank in the form submission? i.e. what is the value in `var_dump($_POST)`? From your screenshot it appears the values of `$name` and `$message` are blank.

Comment: I'm adding a couple of lines of text in the message

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here: 
    `<form name="contactform" action="mailer.php" method="post" role="form" enctype="text/plain">`

You are encoding as "text/plain". Replace with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which is the default or don't include enctype and that will be the default.

Answer (score -2):

you can try it in place of $_POST

```
if ((!is_array($_POST)) || (count($_POST) < 1)) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```

Comment: There is no JSON anywhere in this question. And checking for POST values, then using `php://input`, makes no sense.